# Add/remove class with jquery based on element height scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello i use this jquery function to add a class on the vertical scrolling page. but i want to remove this class on end of an element that it has variable height on all pages.
For example in on page this element height is 400px and on another page it's 1000px and ...
how can i measure the element height and remove the class on that height?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (not tested):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

If user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, then remove class.

Comment: IT'S NOT WORK CORRECTLY

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute a **threshold** (offset element top position + the height of the element = total height from the top of the page to the bottom of the element) and check when it is overtaken by the current scroll position.

It should do the trick:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var threshold = $('.clearHeader').offset().top + $('.clearHeader').height();

    if (scroll >= threshold) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```